# How to save project on runtime?

Tags: livecode

I want to save a project on runtime with extension type ".livecode". Is it possible?

Here is an example:

```
on mouseUp
  save stack "testStack"
end mouseUp
```

---

**I tried this suggestion:**

> In the "Standalone application settings" in LC under "Stacks" enable
>   "Move substacks into individual stackfiles". With this option enabled
>   you can save the substacks from within the standalone.

And I create substack "testsub" in the mainstack.

In the mainstack, I create a button to save the substack. Here is the code:

```
on mouseUp
   save stack "testsub"
end mouseUp
```

It doesn't save the file.

Comment: No file created? - is the path set?  Set the folder to ..... (Check 'folder' in the LC dictionary)

Comment: Do you really try from standalone or from IDE? Trying this from ide, will save the complete stackfile (main + substacks). Only in standalone it will save the separate substack.

Comment: @MatthiasRebbe I can't save substack on runtime ? I build standalone application setting after I create substack on runtime and save it but the substack file doesn't creation. However, I did follow your suggestion.

Comment: @KemChat On what OS are you trying it? If Mac OS, then the individual stack files are placed within the app bundle. First of all you should check if the standalone contains individual stack files -> right click on your standalone app and select "show package content" - or similar. (Don´t have the english description of that menu entry as i am working with a german Mac OS.) Now open the folder MacOS  and you should see the the executable file and the stackfiles. In Windows you should find the stack files in the same folder where the .exe is.

Comment: Do you see the individual stack files? If so, compare the dates of the stackfiles. The one you have saved from within the standalone should show an other date/time than the other files.   IF you cannot see the individual stack files then you should check the "Standalon application settings".

Comment: Can you do the example for me please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can only save substacks. Not the standalone itself.
To save substacks you need to adjust your standalone settings in livecode.

In the "Standalone application settings" in LC under "Stacks" enable "Move substacks into individual stackfiles". With this option enabled you can save the substacks from within the standalone.

Lets say your standalone contains a main stack called "main" and a substack called "preferences".

You can then save the substack with `save stack "preferences"` and the stack is saved back to disk.
You can even save the stack from a script in stack preferences itself. `save this stack`

But as written above, this will only work if the substacks are in seperate stackfiles.
The main stack cannot be saved.

Comment: What dou you mean with "it´s not file from save"?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you can't do what you want, because LiveCode doesn't have permission to write to the application folder (if you're running the app from the application folder). Write the modified stack to the preferences folder or simply to the documents folder and you'll be able to save modifications.